# Missing dll in Matlab R2013b

Tags: matlab, dll

On my previous setup, I was using Matlab R2010 and there was a dll named dformd.dll in the MATLAB2010/bin/win32 folder. However, this dll is missing in the MATLAB2013/bin/win32. Why is it removed from the R2013 version?

Comment: Is the fact that this dll is missing an issue?

Comment: @Schorsch, It's more about the fact that I can't find the dll in the R2013b version, so it must have been removed in the more recent version. I can find the DLL in R2007b and R2010a. Hence, my question is to know when this DLL was removed from the MATLAB installation and how to resolve the issue (do I need to install something new with R2013b that was not needed in previously mentionned version?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dformd.dll seem to be included for the support of Compaq Visual Fortran (CVF). CVF is supported in R2007b version (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/release2007b/)). In more recent version, CVF is not listed as supported. However, the files (such as dformd.dll) were still included with the MATLAB installation for 3 years (R2010b) (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/311489)).